# ActiveRecord: how to build has_many relation with foreign key or null

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have these two models:

```
class Promotion < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :promotions
end
```

And consider these 3 promotions:

```
--------------------------
| PROMOTIONS             |
--------------------------
| id | name | product_id | 
| 1  | sale |    NULL    |
| 2  | 10%  |     1      |
| 3  | 20%  |     2      |
--------------------------
```

When the `product_id` is `NULL`, the promotion applies to all products, so I'd like to be able to get all the promotions for a product as follows:

```
Product.find(1).promotions # => [1,2]
Product.find(2).promotions # => [1,3]
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go about finding promotions like this a few different ways. One way would be to just access the `Promotion` model directly

```
promotions1 = Promotion.where(product_id: [1, nil])
promotions2 = Promotion.where(product_id: [2, nil])
```

You could add this as a method in your `Product` model

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  def all_promotions
    Promotion.where(product_id: [self.id, nil])
  end
end
```

And then use it as follows:

```
Product.find(1).all_promotions # => [1,2]
```

---

Another way could be to concat the promotions of `Product` object with all promotions that aren't attached to a specific product. This definitely isn't the best solution, since you can't really take advantage of `ActiveRecord` to order the promotions; you'd have to use array sorting.

```
def all_promotions
  self.promotions + Promotion.where(product_id: nil)
end
```

Comment: Good solution @Joe, but I think that exists a way to do this providing some option to `has_many` method. Or am I wrong?

Comment: I've been trying to think of one that uses an association, but it seems like that would run counter to the way `ActiveRecord` associations operate. With `has_many`, it's implied that the `promotions` of a `product` are all the `promotions` where `promotions.product_id = products.id` holds true. I don't think there's a way to go about modifying that, because I feel like that could be dangerous.